# Project 3D point to 2D screen coordinates

Tags: java, math, 3d, 2d, projection

I'm trying to project a point from 3D world space to 2D screen coordinates. I have almost everything worked out but I'm having a hard time actually projecting the point.

The setup is as follows:

> Pitch = 90 (all the way up, looking down)
>
> Yaw = 0 (facing north)
>
> Roll = 0 (as normal)

I currently am casting a ray from the camera position through the center of the viewport all the way to the end of the frustum, 
when debugging the ray the values are 0, -1, 0 which means it's facing down so this seems to be correct. Now what I'm trying to achieve is to project the fixed camera point (point on the middle of the ray) from 3D to 2D.

When rotating the camera the projected point should be at the center of the viewport, which it isn't unfortunately.

The current output:

Viewport 800 x 600

```
projectTo2D: vector: Vector4f: 0.0 0.0 500.0 1.0
World matrix:
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0

View matrix:
0.99999994 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 -4.371139E-8 -1.0 2.1855694E-5
0.0 1.0 -4.371139E-8 -500.0
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0

Projection matrix:
-0.75 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 0.0 1.0000999 -0.10000999
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0

Projection world view:
-0.74999994 0.0 0.0 0.0
0.0 -4.371139E-8 -1.0 2.1855694E-5
0.0 1.0000999 -4.3715755E-8 -500.14996
0.0 1.0 -4.371139E-8 -500.0

HDC: Vector4f: 0.0 -499.99997 -500.15 -500.00003
NDC: Vector4f: -0.0 0.9999999 1.0002999 1.0
Viewport coordinates: 400.0, 599.99994
```

Comment: That's way too much code. Try to strip it down to the essential part. What is your actual problem? The projection of a point along a ray through the viewport center is obviously the viewport center.

Comment: Yeah, you're totally right. I got caught up into thinking if I rotated the yaw the projected center should make a perfect circle, the start being the most upper point. But you are totally correct, if I were to project the fixed camera point then this would always be the center of the viewport, but it's not doing that either.

I fixed this in the question and deleted a lot of code, adding more output of the matrices and focussing on the part where it goes wrong. Once I got this working I can continue and try to project some vertices but for now I want this to work.

Thanks for reading & posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are projecting a plain 3d vector. Doing so, you ignore the translation and perspective parts of the matrix. Use a 4d vector with `1` as the `w`-component.

Secondly, you are missing the w-clip:

```
transform(matrix, vector);

vector.x /= vector.w;
vector.y /= vector.w;
vector.z /= vector.w;
vector.w /= vector.w;
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. After doing some Googling I realized I forgot to transform from homogeneous coordinates to clip coordinates. Well I added the division by w under the transform and above the viewport coordinates but still no success (edited the question). Currently when I rotate the yaw 360° I get another curve: http://i.imgur.com/m5oZjiz.png

Comment: A few things: In `toWorldCoordinates()` and `toEyeCoordinates()`, you use `invert()` on a matrix object. I don't know the API, but doesn't that also apply to the original matrix? Why are you replacing z and w components in `toEyeCoordinates()`? Do the w-clip instead. The ray is not necessarily starting at the origin. Therefore, normalizing the resulting point may not work. Furthermore, the way you calculate the point on the ray is not correct in this case. You should subtract the camera position first. Or just calculate the entire ray from two points (one with znear and one with zfar).

Comment: I want to keep the original view matrix and projection matrix since I need to use them again in the `projectTo2D()` method. Using the inverse of these applies in projecting the point to 3D. I am following this tutorial: http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html If you had more information about this w-clip division and where to apply it that would be great. The point on the ray is something I'm not sure about either, I just would like to project the point the camera is fixed at in the middle of the frustum for now, then move on to actual vertices.

Comment: The w-clip (division by w-component) is necessary if you need an actual point at the end. Up to then, you can use the 4D vector. Leave the normalization of the point away.

Comment: I updated the code, for the perspective division but I'm not there yet, I discarded the code for the ray because I want to mainly focus on the projecting part. It seems like I covered everything but I am not getting the desired results + sometimes the values are NaN/Infinity.

Comment: It seems as if you're using column-major matrices. In this case, you need to reverse matrices (`projection * view * world * vector`).

Comment: Doing so flips the y-coordinate: `NDC: 0.0 -1.3333333 0.99979985 1.0 -> Viewport: 400.0, -99.99998` Do you think I've got the matrices setup right? Thanks for helping me and explaining what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I updated the question, so you can see if flips the y-coordinate from -1 to +1. I used another formula for the projection matrix and it seems more accurate now. So the point only displays at -1 or +1 rather than at 0.

Comment: Your transformation looks correct. But the point is not on the view ray. Your camera looks along the y-axis. So, every point of the form `(0, y, 0)` is on the view ray (for any `y`). But don't use `y=500` because this point will be in the camera plane. Those points do not have an image (indicated by the division by zero).

Comment: Thank-you, I got everything working now :) I'm new to 3D and must say I learned a lot!